# what are iframe alternatives that allow dynamic height?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, dynamic

I was trying to set a dynamic height to an iframe but it always fail; I'm looking for an iframe alternative that retrieves contents from webpage and display it in the holder page with dynamic height. Any suggestions?

Comment: dynamic height using jquery or screen height?

Comment: Of course there _are_ other elements that can display web pages inside your document, like `object`, but they all have exactly the same issues. The solution does not lie in using a different element.

Comment: Thanks guys for your support. Question solved, check the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `<head>` section

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

And change your iframe to this:

```
<iframe name="Stack" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```

Comment: Perfect! This one works well 100%. Thank you very much, I Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

search for responsive Iframe on google. There are a lot of tutorials and examples out there.
height:100%; will be an important keyword