# iframe dynamic code strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I use the following code to get a dynamic height iframe.

In the `<head>` section

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
</script>
```

In the `<body>`

```
<iframe name="somepage" src="somepage.html" width="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' /></iframe>
```

This code is working perfect on my domain account and compatible with all browsers. However, it didn't work at all when I tested it on another domain account. I transferred the files (copied & pasted them), they are 100% the same. I can't see where the problem! Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the domain names...

Comment: Are both HTML pages (frame and container) in the same domain?

Comment: That was the trick! I updated the links in there. Thank you very much, I appreciate it. @Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! Thanks to [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464627/jason)

The iframe page links wasn't in the same domain that transferred to . I updated the links with the new domain name and it worked fine. I wanted to share my experience, if anyone face this problem, this post may help.

Also if you want to have a dynamic iframe height the above code works well (Thanks to [pankaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348626/pankaj-kumar-singh) from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20263033/what-are-iframe-alternatives-that-allow-dynamic-height)), Have a good day!